# react router redux express API loading state

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router, redux

How do you guys usually go about doing the loading part of your react? Since pages load really fast now, it's my API request who's having a hard time keeping up. For express, I have a Promise to wait for the API's return data before serving the pages.

```
export default function fetchComponentData(dispatch, components, params) {
  const needs = components.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return current ? (current.needs || []).concat(prev) : prev;
  }, []);

  const promises = needs.map(need => dispatch(need(params)));

  return Promise.all(promises);
}

...

fetchComponentData(store.dispatch, props.components, _.merge({}, props.params, props.location.query))
        .then(setupHTML)
        .then(html => res.end(html))
```

But should I do this to react as well? Or how do you guys usually display the pages while it's loading? My current is I display the page without the data and start fetching and then rerender to display the page with the content, but then I have a small flickering page which I bet would be annoying if it's deployed already. I usually have my reducers (states) in this format:

```
const defaultState = {
  ui: {
    loading: false
  }, metadata: {
  }, 
  data: { }
}
```

I was wondering how do you guys usually approach this?

Comment: In my opinion, this is a clear-cut case where your project could benefit from implementation of isomorphic React. Perform your initial render on the server, then have your client-side React follow up with checking diffs.

Comment: Yes. I am using isomorphic react here. My issue or question is regarding transitioning to pages afterwards.